# How can I center an image in this kind of script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, centering

I've tried various approaches,

I've no clue how to do it without destroying the script or rescripting it all.
Here's a link to the page: http://hem.bredband.net/noor/bildspelet.html

You need to click the edit button on the top left, put 2 URLs to pictures, take these e.g.
http://barcelona.magicka-evropa.cz/images/fc-barcelona.jpg

http://tux.crystalxp.net/png/uttaresh-fc-barcelona-13276.png

You'll notice the pictures aren't centered.. I haven't put in any code to center it in the example.. How can i go about to do that?

Comment: Do you want each picture centred in a vertical group or to centre the pair of images? Using margin { 0 auto } should do it.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the page. I'd made an error with one of the .js files.. anyways, i want it to be centered both horizontically and vertically. I'm going to turn this into a fullscreen slideshow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're using the jQuery Cycle Lite Plugin.  If so, the plugin provides an event called "after" which you would want to listen to.

In that callback, you would want to check if the image is downloaded already or not.  Once its downloaded, you would execute your logic to center the image.

Comment: I've got the implementation of the after function right, no clue how to center the image though

Comment: sounds like another question for so!